# NSUserDefaults does not persist data

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, data-persistence

I am using user defaults to store information between app launches. This is the code I am using in App Delegate:

```
var kaki: Bool!

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if kaki == nil{
            print("kaki is nil")
            kaki = false
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(kaki, forKey: "kaki")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            print("kaki now has value")


    }else{
            print("kaki already has value")

            kaki = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("kaki") as! Bool
    }



func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(kaki, forKey: "kaki")
         NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
```

In my viewController I have this code:

```
@IBAction func makeButtonRedIfKakiIsTrue(sender: UIButton) {
    print("kaki is \(appDel.kaki)")
    if appDel.kaki == true{
        restoreItems.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    appDel.kaki = true
}
```

I run this code, thank click the button `makeButtonRedIfKakiIsTrue`, shut down the application. And launch it again from device. I click the button, but the color doesn't change. Why does not change? Because `kaki` is once again `false`, although I set it to be true when I previously clicked  `makeButtonRedIfKakiIsTrue`. I conclude....NSUserDefaults didn't save information between launches. Why?

Comment: Read this explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21868541/1463604

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you try saving `true` instead of `false`? Would you get the same result?

Comment: There are designated methods `boolForKey:` and `setBool:forKey:` of `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: @Nishant I am indeed already calling synchornize in willResignActive. I also added it in didEnterBackground. Same result.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i switched true and false at all places but still getting the same result. I was advised to use objectForKey

Comment: My god I feel stupid. I forgot to add this oneliner at the beginning of the didFinishLaunching        `kaki = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("kaki") as! Bool`

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add `kaki = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("kaki") as? Bool` at the beginning of `didFinishLauncing` method